# Background check leading to offer getting rescinded

Tags: background-check, rejection, job-acceptance

I currently accepted and signed a job offer for Company A since they did not give more time and I had no choice. The joining date would be 6 months after I signed the offer. 2 months before the joining date I got an offer from Company B which is better in all aspects and hence I accepted and signed offer letter for Company B.
(It is unethical on my part, yes, but it was a dream offer)

Now, I was planning to contact Company A to apologize for the initial acceptance when Company B starts their background check. Company A is listed in my resume as I did an internship with them.

Since Company B can still reject me based on my background check( even though i have not done anything wrong), I am not sure if I should email Company A about me reneging on the offer. At the same time, I am worried that Company B may find out about my job acceptance for Company A and can reject me (I don't know if that is possible or will they contact me before rescinding my offer).

Hence, should I email Company A about my rejection or wait till Company B completes their background check? I do not want to finally lose both the offers.

In short,

1. Accepted and signed Company A offer
2. Accepted and signed Company B offer
3. Company B starts background check where Company A is listed as
   places I have interned.
   Should I wait for B to finish check or email A saying I can't take up the offer?

Comment: How does the background check work with respect to who you work for in the past? All they do is check the employers on your CV are correct. Unless you have told company A about company B or vice versa, how will they ever know?

Comment: This needs a retitle, but I'm not sure what the actual **question** is. "What should I do?" is off-topic.

Comment: @Lilienthal Should I wait for B to finish background check after which I should tell A about not joining or should I tell now itself?

Comment: @EdHeal I am not aware on how exactly background checks work. I want to join B, A is listed in my resume as I did an internship with them. hence B  will contact A at least for checking if I worked there.

Comment: What country are you from @Huga? A six month wait to start a new job is extremely long in most parts of the world.

Comment: @DavidHammen ; USA-- The offer was made right after a summer internship. I could join only after I graduate which would be 6 months after that time. Hence the 6 months

Answer (score 4, accepted):

6 months is a long time to wait before starting a job. Your best option is to get out of Company A's offer as soon as possible. As far as worrying about the background check being a problem, I can't see it causing you an issue, there is nothing you can do about it, and you can explain if asked.

So best not to worry about it unduly.

Comment: 1. Will background checks reveal that I accepted A's offer? Also, I got the offer right after my internship and I had 6 more months to graduate. Hence the 6 month wait. But still they did not give me an option to postpone my decision.

Comment: It's unlikely to bring up that you accepted the offer, there is no way of telling how deep they will dig, but it doesn't matter if it finds out